# Is there an "easy" way to check if array is sorted in Zig

Tags: zig

I have an i64 array of 4 elements and I want to check if it's sorted after calling the sorting algorithm on it.

```
fn cmpByValue(context: void, a: i64, b: i64) bool {
    return std.sort.asc(i64)(context, a, b);
}

test selectionSort {
    var values = [_]i64{ 60, 50, 250, 450 };
    selectionSort(&values);
    try std.testing.expect(std.sort.isSorted(i64, &values, {}, cmpByValue));
}
```

This is a solution that I found, but coming from a python/go/c++ background I would guess that there should be an easier solution to this problem.

Overall it seems to me like zig is quite barebones with the functions it provides. (which isn't bad, just something that I'm observing while learning it)

Comment: What does "easy" mean to you? I think anything simpler than `std.sort.isSorted` would go against Zig's philosophy. Since it would mean that the language/STD would have to make assumptions.

Comment: "easy" means for example isSorted(array) or array.isSorted().

I have no problem if it's zigs philosophy, just was wondering if there is this kind of easier solution, as I guess I'm used to not having to write comprasion which of ints is bigger.

Comment: You should not test by using the very thing you are testing. You know the right answer: `{ 50, 60, 250, 450 }`. So test whether the array looks like that.

Comment: Yeah right in simple case like this it's easy, but if the array gets longer it will get tedious to copy paste it. Also this way i can change the checked array and then don't have to change the expected output. I think that approach makes code easier to read as you instantly see in expect that it's checked if it's sorted instead of making std.mem.eql (which isn't that obvious for reader who isn't familiar with zig). Well as the solution I guess I could change the test name to better reflect this.

Comment: I think that response misses the point of what testing is.

Answer (score 0):

why not just

```
std.sort.isSorted(i64, &values, {}, std.sort.asc(i64));
```

the wrapper is unnecessary.

Also to comment on your question about there being an "easy" way, there's no array.isSorted() because arrays and other base types (integers, floats, @Vectors, pointers) don't support methods. Because zig has a focus on allowing a "no std" option.

The isSorted method takes more than just the array because there are things you need to be able to control when it comes to sorting. Whether it's ascending/descending/custom, passing context so that you can sort correctly without globals, etc.